# Is it possible to create shareable links in G Suite Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace-for-business

I am deciding if I should get G Suite or not.

I need to share public files with everyone.

Is it possible to create shareable links in G Suite Drive, just like the ones you create in Google Drive for personal use?

Comment: yes it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Drive for G Suite has the same features that Google Drive for consumers / Google common accounts but it extend several of them including settings and special features for organization administrators.